# i encounter an spacing error on css media print on h2, h3, h4 and the table content

Tags: css, media

i encounter an spacing error on css media print on h2, h3, h4 and the table content.
the text suppose to be extended on the right side as well as the table content.

see this image below for the spacing error:

[image]

html:

```html
<h2>QA Template -MEL - pls do not touch - 739</h2>
<div class="header-description">
        Some description text to fill the emptiness....&nbsp; This is a test, This is a test, This is a test, This is a test, This is a test.
    </div>
<h3>Scale Section (Subs, Grouped)</h3>
<h4>Scale Sub 1 (Mandatory)</h4>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="table-header">
      <th id="ctl00_MainContentPlaceholder_C001_rptReports_ctrl0_rptIndividualQuestions_ctrl0_tdHeader" scope="col"> <span class="question-text">Question </span> </th>
      <th scope="col"> Very Good </th>
      <th scope="col"> Good </th>
      <th scope="col"> Normal </th>
      <th scope="col"> Bad </th>
      <th scope="col"> Very Bad </th>
      <th scope="col"> Don't Know </th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="table-alt-row ">
      <td><span class="question-text">Question 1. </span> <a tabindex="0" class="tooltip tooltipstered" id="tooltip_e1872f64-db9a-6d2b-9fad-ff0000a141dd0" aria-describedby="data_tooltip_e1872f64-db9a-6d2b-9fad-ff0000a141dd0">Question 1. Scale Q1 - QA Scale, Sub1, Can Filter</a> <span role="tooltip" class="tooltip-content" id="data_tooltip_e1872f64-db9a-6d2b-9fad-ff0000a141dd0"> <span class="question-text">Question 1. </span> <br>
        Scale Q1 - QA Scale, Sub1, Can Filter </span></td>
      <td> 3<br>
        75.0 % </td>
      <td> 1<br>
        25.0 % </td>
      <td> 0<br>
        0.0 % </td>
      <td> 0<br>
        0.0 % </td>
      <td> 0<br>
        0.0 % </td>
      <td> 0<br>
        0.0 % </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="table-header"> </tr>
    <tr class="table-row ">
      <td><span class="question-text">Question 2. </span> <a tabindex="0" class="tooltip tooltipstered" id="tooltip_f1872f64-db9a-6d2b-9fad-ff0000a141dd1" aria-describedby="data_tooltip_f1872f64-db9a-6d2b-9fad-ff0000a141dd1">Question 2. Scale Q2 - QA Scale, Sub1, Can Not Filter</a> <span role="tooltip" class="tooltip-content" id="data_tooltip_f1872f64-db9a-6d2b-9fad-ff0000a141dd1"> <span class="question-text">Question 2. </span> <br>
        Scale Q2 - QA Scale, Sub1, Can Not Filter </span></td>
      <td> 0<br>
        0.0 % </td>
      <td> 2<br>
        50.0 % </td>
      <td> 1<br>
        25.0 % </td>
      <td> 1<br>
        25.0 % </td>
      <td> 0<br>
        0.0 % </td>
      <td> 0<br>
        0.0 % </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

my css media print below:

```
html {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    *,  *:before,  *:after {
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    * {
        background: transparent !important;
        color: black !important;
        /* Black prints faster: h5bp.com/s */
        box-shadow: none !important;
        text-shadow: none !important;
    }
    a,  a:visited {
        text-decoration: underline;
    }
    a[href]:after {
        content: " (" attr(href) ")";
    }
    abbr[title]:after {
        content: " (" attr(title) ")";
    }
    .ir a:after,  a[href^="javascript:"]:after,  a[href^="#"]:after {
        content: "";
    }
    pre,  blockquote {
        border: 1px solid #999999;
        page-break-inside: avoid;
    }
    thead {
        display: table-header-group;
    /* h5bp.com/t */ }
    tr,  img {
        page-break-inside: avoid;
    }
    img {
        max-width: 100% !important;
        height: auto;
        -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
    @page {
        margin: 0.5cm;
    }
    p,  h2,  h3,  h4 {
        orphans: 3;
        widows: 3;
    }
    textarea {
        height: auto;
        min-height: 50px;
    }
    select {
        width: 100%;
    }
    section {
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        background: none;
    }
    #showNoSchoolMessage, header, footer, .m-contentHeader, #MainContentPlaceholder_C001_pnlFilterReports, .l-cr15.sf_cols, #MainContentPlaceholder_C001_pnlButtons, .survey-action,  .large-button {
        display: none;
    }
    h2 {
        font-size: 20pt;
        page-break-after: avoid;
        margin: 0 !important;
        padding: 0 !important;
    }
    h3 {
        font-size: 18pt;
        page-break-after: avoid;
        margin: 0 !important;
        padding: 0 !important;
    }
    h4 {
        font-size: 16pt;
        page-break-after: avoid;
        margin: 0 !important;
        padding: 0 !important;
    }
    p,  h2,  h3,  h4 {
        orphans: 3;
        widows: 3;
    }
    .survey-report .report-item-list .report-item .donut-block {
        height: auto;
    }
    .table-block table {
    }
    .report-item-list > .report-item {
        page-break-after: always;
        display: block;
    }
    table tr {
        page-break-inside: avoid;
    }
```

thanks!

Comment: Without posting your CSS, we are useless to you.

Comment: supposed to be there..

Comment: Take a look at [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) when writing your question. Now, without the appropriate HTML to complement your CSS... we are still pretty useless to you.

Comment: i already added the css.

Comment: I said HTML, not CSS.

Comment: sorry, already added

Answer (score 0):

Adding a width of 100% to the table resolves its extendability issue. I'm not seeing a problem with the headers as you mentioned.

```
table {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/h4362ogf/